# Automatically generate legend for graphs in r?

Tags: r, styles, plot, legend

Is it somehow possible, to automatically generate a legend in R? One thing that really annoys me, is redundant information, that I have to enter to show the legend (for example the line colour,...)

```
plot(
  c(1:5), c(.7, 2.2, 3.1, 3.9, 5.2),
  col=1,
  pch=3,
  type="b"
)

lines(
  c(1:5), c(1:5),
  col=2,
  pch=6,
  type="o"
)

legend(
  "topleft",
  legend=c("data", "expactation"),
  col=c(1, 2),
  pch=c(3, 6),
  lty=c(2 ,1)
)
```

I already gave information about the line colour,... in the commands `plot` and `lines`. It would be nice, if I do not have to add this information again in legend.

Is it for example possible to store the "lines"-Object and "plot"-object in a variable and only pass these objects to legend (where legend finds the required information)?

```
p = plot(...)
l = lines (...)
legend("topleft", p, l)
```

Comment: Try looking at `ggplot2`

Comment: As the answers have indicated, you're asking for a lot of work.  Consider that you can choose to create a legend that has different sized symbols (or linewidths) than the graph itself for clarity, or you might want to indicate that all dotted lines, regardless of color, refer to a group of variables, etc.  So you're not really likely to have a general "auto-legend" format in the first place.  R is way better than E--l  (an unnamed spreadsheet app) in this respect.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it for example possible to store the "lines"-Object and
>   "plot"-object in a variable and only pass these objects to legend
>   (where legend finds the required information)

Not easily. However, ggplot2 gives you this functionality. For example,

```
##Create some data and load the library
dd = data.frame(x = c(1:5,1:5), y = c(.7, 2.2, 3.1, 3.9, 5.2, 1:5), 
                type=rep(c("data", "expectation"), each=5))

require(ggplot2)
```

Next we create a `plot` object`:

```
##Legend is automatically generated
g = ggplot(data=dd, aes(x = x, y=y)) + 
    geom_point(aes(colour=type, pch=type))
g
```

Not we add some lines to the "plot object":

```
g + geom_line(aes(colour=type, pch=type))
```

Answer (score 2):

No, not without an awful lot of work and a wrapper too the `plot` function so that you record the styles specified once and pass them on to the various plotting functions and the legend.

The **ggplot2** and **lattice** packages are higher-level approaches where this sort of thing *is* automated for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize the legend if you want it to look like your plot. Lattice technically got `auto.key` option, but it gives you ugly default colours and points type. But you can easily store your parameters' values before you make a plot, and then pass them to the corresponding arguments. Below is an example with lattice:

```
#your example data
d <- data.frame(a=rep(1:5,2), b=c(.7, 2.2, 3.1, 3.9, 5.2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
                c=rep(c("data", "expactation"),each=5))
#your `pch` and 'col` you pass to the plot
pch.a <- c(3,6)
col.a <- 1:2
library(lattice)
xyplot(a ~ b, groups=c, data = d, type="o", col=col.a, pch=pch.a, aspect=1/2,
       key = list(points=list(pch=pch.a, col=col.a), text=list(levels(d$c))))
```

[image]